# WiX - Cancel upgrade if previous version is not same configuration (Debug/Release)

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I'm having some issues with custom actions not working properly (and causing broken installations) when trying to install a Debug build on top of a Release build, or vice-versa. Therefore I'd like to prevent such upgrades completely, and force the user to manually uninstall first.

So far I have this:

```
<?if $(var.Configuration) = Debug?>
    <?define DisallowUpgrade = "yes"?>
<?else?>
    <?define DisallowUpgrade = "no"?>
<?endif?>

<MajorUpgrade Disallow="$(var.DisallowUpgrade)" ... />
```

This forces the user to always uninstall first when installing a Debug build (which is fine). However it does not stop a Release build from trying to upgrade over a Debug build. How can I do this?

Thanks!

---

P.S. As I was typing I just thought of increasing the version number for Debug builds -- say by adding 100 to it. This would work, but could lead to confusion with QA people, so I'd prefer a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would a "user" ever know what a debug / release build is?  IMO a user should only ever see a release build.

I would suggest build debug MSI and release MSI as two different products (upgrade code and even destination directory if you want side by side installs ) and a debug can only upgrade a debug and a release can only upgrade a release and only release MSIs ever go out the door to customers.

And of course, the less custom actions the better. :)

Comment: Our debug builds include a bunch of extra features for internal testing; they don't go to customers. And we'd have to extensively rewrite our product to support side-by-side installs.

Having them as two separate products would be fine; is it possible to do that while ensuring only one can be installed at a time?

Comment: Yes. Each Product could have a Upgrade entry using the detect only attribute for the other product's UpgardeCode.  Then a launch condition that blocks installation if the opposite program is detected.

Answer (score 0):

Write `$(var.Configuration)` to the registry, use `RegistrySearch` to load it, and use `Condition` to compare what's in the registry with the current value of `$(var.Configuration)`.